# React-Native ToolbarAndroid does not support fontFamily

Tags: android, react-native, android-toolbar, android-fonts

I have custom fonts working in my project using React Native's in-built support for cross-platform custom fonts. I'm curious if there is anyway to apply `fontFamily` to the ToolbarAndroid component (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html ). Unfortunately, the toolbar `style` does not support the key.

I also attempted setting title to a component `myTitle` and feeding it to the toolbars `title` attribute, but this results in a cyclic error:

```
var myTitle = <Text style={{fontFamily: 'MyFont'}}>My Profile</Text>
```

Ideally, I would love to keep the native toolbar rather than replace it with a custom JS toolbar that supports custom fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by placing the `mytitle` component, using custom `fontFamily`, within the ToolbarAndroid tags like so:

```
<ToolbarAndroid>{mytitle}</ToolbarAndroid>
```

Rather than trying to place the component within the `title` attribute of ToolbarAndroid.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for taking the time to post how you solved this :) You should mark this as answer.